# Python Spell Correct

Tags: python, spell-checking, pyenchant

I am trying to write python script to do spell correction for languages - ENGLISH[GB], GERMAN, SPANISH, ITALIAN, FRENCH.

As a first step, I installed **pyenchant** in my machine[**64bit, python 2.7**] and when I tried to import enchant package, I got following error message.

```
*ImportError: The 'enchant' C library was not found. Please install it via your OS package manager, or use a pre-built binary wheel from PyPI.*
```

When I googled the error message, I got to know that 64-bit version of enchant package is not available yet.

Can someone help me with using enchant package or any other package/technique to do spell correction for above mentioned **five** languages.

Answer (score 0):

pyenchant can do your spelling check in all five languages *under python 32 bit* - if you **have** to use 64 bit python then you will need to build enchant and pyenchant for 64 bit and resolve any issues yourself.

Note that 32 bit python works fine, for most usages, on 64 bit machines and in general more libraries are supported.

For installing on Python 2.7 (32 bit) all you should need to do is:

```
pip install -U pyenchant
```

If you are having problems after this the next step is to uninstall and reinstall:

```
pip uninstall pyenchant
pip install -U pyenchant
```

but you can also use the [cheese shop](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyenchant) downloads, if you are having problems I would recommend, for simplicity, just using the [Windows Installer](https://pypi.python.org/packages/any/p/pyenchant/pyenchant-1.6.6.win32.exe#md5=d2aa030d21eebd74f80a62ce9ef75f1d) *link is for the version 1.6.6 windows installer*.

Comment: Thanks... I used 32-bit python and installed **pyenchant**   `pip install pyenchant` ...   then imported it in python `import enchant'... but I got following error message **`ImportError: The 'enchant' C library was not found. Please install it via your OS package manager, or use a pre-built binary wheel from PyPI.`**...   my OS is windows... can you help how can I resolve this error message..